# Operator = overloading with templates

Tags: c++, overloading

Seriously, I looked at similar examples, but I still do not get why it is not working. I am having trouble with overloading the = operator.

I get the two following errors:

1. error C2955: 'Matrix' : use of class template requires template argument list
2. error C2244: 'Matrix::operator =' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration

May someone please explain what is wrong?

Thanks to all

```
//Matrix.hpp

template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix(int numberRows, int numberColumns);
    ~Matrix();
    void asgValue(T value, int row, int column);
    T getValue(int row, int column);
    Matrix<T>& operator= (const Matrix<T>& rhs);
    friend Matrix<T>& operator+ (const Matrix<T>& lhs, const Matrix<T>& rhs);
private:
    T **twoDarray;
    int nbrRows;
    int nbrColumns;
};

#include "Matrix.inl"

//Matrix.inl

//Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator= (const Matrix<T>& rhs)
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix::operator= (const Matrix<T>& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nbrRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nbrColumns; j++)
        {
            twoDarray[i][j] = rhs.twoDarray[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: If `rhs` has a different number of rows or columns, I think you're going to have a bad time. I think you should be setting `nbrRows` and `nbrColumns` from `rhs.nbrRows` and `rhs.nbrColumns`, and allocating a new `twoDarray`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will surely look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need template parameters in the *name* of the function being defined.

```
template<typename T>
Matrix<T>& Matrix<T>::operator= (const Matrix<T>& rhs)
               // ^ here
```

You are required to write `<T>`, although it doesn't add to the expressiveness of the language — the arguments before `::` cannot be anything other than the entire class template parameter list in the original order and without any modifications. It is what it is.

Comment: +1 Or stating *the arguments before `::` cannot be anything other than the entire class template parameter list*, the left hand side of `::` must be a namespace or a *class*, and a template is neither

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True, but given that the standard goes out of its way to specify what template arguments are allowed for that *class-name*, it might have been easier to forbid template-ids there and require a template-name instead.